# How to call tableview reloadData from another viewcontroller

Tags: swift

I am trying to reload the tableview after UIBarbutton is clicked to  save a multi line text in UserDefaults.I want to update the tableview cell which is in another view controller after the button is clicked and load the cell but its not working for me.I tried to add an observer but its not working.The cell will show after reopening the app.What i am missing here?

```
@objc func saveTapped(){
        guard let fact = savedFact else {
            return
        }
        let deviceID = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
        savedValues.append(fact)
        if let arr =  UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: deviceID){
            
            var arrvalues = arr as! [String]
            if !arrvalues.contains(fact){
                arrvalues.append(fact)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(arrvalues, forKey:deviceID)
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                print (arr)
            }
            else
            {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(savedValues, forKey:deviceID)
            }
            
        }
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
    }
```

FavoritesViewController

```
class FavoritesViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    var savedList = [String]()
    
    private func deleteFavorites(text:String){
        let deviceID = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
        
        if let arr =  UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: deviceID){
            var arrvalues = arr as! [String]
            if let index = arrvalues.firstIndex(of:text){
                arrvalues.remove(at: index)
                savedList.remove(at: index)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(arrvalues, forKey:deviceID)
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
                
            }
            
        }
    }

 
    
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
 
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(loadList), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
        
        let deviceID = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
        
        savedList = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: deviceID) as? [String] ?? []
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "FavoritesTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: FavoritesTableViewCell.identifier)
        
    }
    @objc func loadList(notification: NSNotification){
        //load data here
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        
    }
    
}

extension FavoritesViewController {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return savedList.count
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FavoritesTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! FavoritesTableViewCell
        cell.cellBgImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 9
        cell.factsLabel.text = savedList[indexPath.row]
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       if editingStyle == .delete {
        deleteFavorites(text: savedList[indexPath.row])
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
       
        
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
@objc func loadList(notification: NSNotification){
    //load data here
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
}
```

as

```
@objc func loadList(notification: NSNotification){
    //load data here
    savedList = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: deviceID) as? [String] ?? []
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know a way, but I don't know if it's the best one.

I always suggest having a shared variable document. In that document, store a variable, which type is FavoritesViewController (in your case).

In FavoritesViewController `viewDidLoad()`, assign `self` to the shared variable.

Then, in each other document, subsequently, you can call each method of your FavoritesViewController